# Spritekit game lagging even at 60fps

Tags: sprite-kit, lag, skspritenode

I'm currently making a side-scrolling platform game in *SpriteKit*, but even though the game is running at *60fps*, it is a bit laggy. Does anyone know what could cause this? And in that case: how I can solve it?

I think it might be relevant that I'm making a so-called `tiled-game`, in which everything is built up by `32x32` blocks. There isn't more than `100-150 nodes` (all with `physics-bodies`) on-screen simultaneously, but I constantly keep the current "level" loaded into the `background layer`, and that could contain up to around a `thousand blocks` (with `physics-bodies`). When the player moves around on screen, I simply move this layer around. The lag seems to occur when the `background-layer` is moving, and I think the problem might be related to keeping all of these `physics bodies` loaded in at once (even though they're not on screen). However, I thought `SpriteKit` kept track of this itself, and solved those kind of problems.

However, if you think this is the problem, what is your suggestion to solving it?

Comment: post relevant sections of your code. how did you determine 60 fps? describe what the lag appears to be like, ie hiccup every second? try removing parts of your code, ie do not assign physicsbodies.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I have a lot of code, and figuring out what sections are relevant to this problem without knowing what's causing it is on the border of impossible. I know it's running at 60fps because that's what the debug-info in SpriteKit says it's running at. The lag is random, sometimes it's completely smooth, and sometimes it's very laggy - I cannot find a pattern. 

I will try not assigning physicsbodies, and see how that works. I'll post an update when I've had the chance to try it :)

Comment: without at least seeing the code and having narrowed it down it's also impossible to debug it from afar ;)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I totally understand that, but I was just wondering if you had any experience or immediate assumptions that could help finding out where to look?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I'm not completely sure, because the lag is very random - but there seem to be no lag when I remove most of the physics bodies (the ones related to bricks forming ground, walls, roofs, objects etc). But I need these for the game to function - how would you proceed to eliminate the lag but keep the game mechanics as they are?

Comment: deactive all physics bodies not currently in the visible playfield, specifically they shouldn't cause any contact events. One way might be to change them from dynamic to static (dynamic=NO)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D All of the physics bodies I removed in the example already have `dynamic = NO`, that's why I find it really weird...